# Is there a modelling of Wave Rock (Hyden Rock) formation?

Tags: rocks, geomorphology, numerical-modelling, simulation

I'm interested in the visualization of the formation process of "strange" objects like [Wave Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_Rock) (flared slope). I've found articles describing hypotheses of the rock formation but I cannot find mathematical modeling (computer simulation) of it. Aren't modeling approaches of rocks popular in geomorphology because of complexity, long time periods to cover, and a lot of factors to take into account?

Comment: I doubt such a thing exists. It might help if you posted the articles you've read in order to avoid that people repeat the things that are written there.

Comment: @a_donda, I've read this one https://www.udc.es/files/iux/almacen/articulos/cd27_art03.pdf, though the question is not about the exact hypothesis. Could you, please, explain your doubt?

Comment: Well, exactly because of the points you mentioned: complexity and time. Too many unknowns. If you mean by "mathematical approaches" a simulation of the physics that lead to the feature. Tafoni and "flared slopes" may point in the direction ? I am not sure about the latter ...

Comment: Wave Rock isn't a significant geological structure that would require geologists to spend a lot of time analyzing it. It's effectively a granite dome that has one side eroded in the shape of a wave. The wave itself in no more than 2 m high & maybe 10 m long. It's located on featureless plane, surrounded by wheat or canola pastures. It's promoted by the locals to entice tourism to the sparsely populated region.